# Discord.py bot doesn't play wav/mp3 file

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
import requests
import json

from apikeys import *

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is now ready for use!")
    print("-----------------------------")
 
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    if (ctx.author.voice): 
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio("song.wav")
        player =  voice.play(source)
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not in a voice channel")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
    if (ctx.voice_client):
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await ctx.send("I left the voice channel")
    else:
        await ctx.send("I am not in a voice channel")

client.run(BOTTOKEN)
```

Hey! I have recently started watching a tutorial series.
It works for the tutorial maker, but doesn't for me.
The bot is able to join the voice channel the user is in, but never starts playing "song.wav".
Sadly Visual Studio Code also doesn't output any Error messages.
Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Did you install all the libraries and modules?

Comment: Yeah, unless I missed any